# Use JQuery UI Accordion for mobile menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using the [JQuery UI Accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion) to expand content within the body content of a website.

Here's the basic markup for that:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <div>Content</div>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <div>Content</div>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <div>Content</div>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

I'd like to use [JQuery UI Accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion) for my mobile menu too.

Here's the structure I currently have for the nav:

```
<!-- Desktop menu -->
<nav class="desktop">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="page-one">Page One</a></li>
        <li><a href="page-two">Page Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="page-three">Page Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="page-four">Page Four</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<!-- Mobile menu -->
<nav class="mobile accordion">
    <span>Menu</span>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="page-one">Page One</a></li>
        <li><a href="page-two">Page Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="page-three">Page Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="page-four">Page Four</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The menus are being activated by a simple media query:

```
.mobile {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 48em) {
    .desktop {
        display: none;
    }

    .mobile {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this so I don't need to repeat my nav markup?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it width a litle javascript, first you can´t put a div or span inside an ul if they are not in a li, so you have to take out the span width the menu text, here you have an example... you can play width animations, etc

```
<nav>
<span class="show-nav">Menu</span>
<ul class="accordion">
    <li><a href="page-one">Page One</a></li>
    <li><a href="page-two">Page Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="page-three">Page Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="page-four">Page Four</a></li>
</ul>
```

//CSS

```
.show-nav{
  display:none;
 }
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .show-nav{
    display:block;
  }
  .accordion{
    display:block;
     max-height: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;   
  }
  .accordion.open{
    max-height: 500px;
  }
}
```

//Javascript

```
    $('.show-nav').click(function(){
      $('.accordion').toggleClass('open');
    })
```

https://codepen.io/marcosefrem/pen/aLqvrw

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the markup. Is there a way I can utilise JQuery UI Accordion instead of the line of JS you've included?

Comment: Sorry for not responding before, I think the behavior you want to do, you have to do like this or similar, if you are not using some framework like boostrap that already has these behaviors included in their libraries, and here you are trying to do un menu that is not the same than accordeon, and not use the same code, accordeon Jquery UI needs h3 + div and here you have to do a list of elements.

Comment: No worries. JQuery UI Accordion can work with any html element as the header (in this case `<span>Menu</span>`). See the documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-header).